# Does this magic system stray way too far from the realm of medieval fantasy?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, dragons, medieval

I have thought of a magic system, I’ve just thought about it so it’s not a system really. There is a special kind of metal that when a magical powder touches, a practicer of the arts can cast a spell.

One of the spells are lighting out of a wand made of this metal, which is kind of like a gun from the Second World War in its rate of fire and accuracy. Another is like artillery, which would render walls useless except for keeping raiders and bandits away from cities and towns. One is like a mine that explodes when stepping on it. People can make a shell around themselves, basically tanks. And there are things like radios where if you want to speak to someone you leave your body and go to another “dimension” where you speak to the person you want to talk to. Dragons are there too, they are common but not as common as horse. They are the same size of a horse

My world is supposed to have this medieval feeling to it. It should feel like you’re breathing in the smell of pig shit staining the muddy streets of the town as you ride in on your stallion and stop at the inn, you can still hear the bard’s singing as you try to sleep and be off on your journey. **Does any of what I have stated above tarnish this? Does it detach you from medieval fantasy? And if so what changes do you suggest? Or do you think I should just remove the magic system?**

**If everyone could perform this magic, does it add or remove from the fantastical element? Or does it not make any difference?**

**If you see, as you most probably will, any flaws in the magic system please write it down**

Comment: This is very opinion-based an open multiple question. Your world is what you how you make it. What's the difference beetwen Ak47 and fireballs? A grenade and "exploding spell"? You, as the author, have a power to limit, excess or just keep magic in fairy tales of your world.

Comment: Is using this magic effectively something that requires training and dedication (like a sword or a longbow), or is it closer to "point-and-click" (like a crossbow or a gun) once the manufacturing is done?

Comment: This question is off-topic (determining the genre of a story is more Writing.SE material) but it is also opinion-based when phrased like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Gunpowder heavily change european medieval society, expect your magic to do as well.

Gunpowder is probably the technology that had the most impact on late medieval ages, not only making chivalry much less effective, but leading to the end of feudalism.

Feudalism is a hierarchical system, where each noble swear fealty to its upper rank noble, in exchange of protection.

A local noble will give part of his army to it's count, but the count should also protect his noble, and it worked well for quite long, untill gunpowder become effective, making the whole castle and feudalism system much less effective.

Not only a canon can wipe out walls of your castle, (even walls of constantinople falls, so one couldn't expect anymore to have unbreachable defence), making the local noble very vulnerable, but the whole paiment system was broken, as the local noble couldn't produce guns.

Guns need high level of mettalurgy, some standardisation, and lot of money, so instead of producing it's own guns, the local noble give money to upper rank noble so he can produce more guns.

It make the state much more centralized, unlike early medieal period, with vassals with lot of independence.

Your magic system is very close to gunpowder in terms of destruction power, and may ask lot of ressources to form mage. Blast furnace and heavy industry to create cannons were only present in big cities, so will be your mage-forming academy.

Take inspiration from late middle ages or even renaissance, rather than early or high middle age